# Changing Boolean to boolean throws noSuchMethodError in MapStruct

Tags: java, hibernate, boolean, mapstruct

I have a Boolean defined by hibernate

```
public class MyClassWithMyVar {

     @Column(name="myVar", nullable=false)
     private Boolean myVar;

     public Boolean getMyVar(){
         return myVar;
     }

     public void setMyVar(Boolean myVar){
         this.myVar=myVar;
     }

}
```

we do know that this Boolean should never be null, this is being used in some mappers by mapstruct

```
@Mapper
@Mappings({@Mapping(target = "id", ignore =true)})
abstract MyClassWithMyVar copyMyClassWithMyVar(MyClassWithMyVar myClassWithMyVar);
```

and then I change all places where I have Boolean to boolean, run my application and throws a NoSuchMethodError:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MyClassWithMyVar.getMyVar()Ljava/lang/Boolean;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mapstruct follows JavaBeans specification, and JavaBeans specification http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/ says that:

> for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern: `public boolean is<PropertyName>();`

is should be used for boolean (primitive type)
when we do want to return objects then we use getX() for example for Boolean getMyBoolean().

Comment: I think that we should do a null check in such case. Can you please open an issue?

Comment: I do not think so, if we do have nullable=false, give us the information that we do not want this to be null, but you can write another answer if you think another answer will be better

Comment: What I meant is that MapStruct should generate code like you would do by writing it by hand. btw. I am one of the developers that works on MapStruct. I thought that this might be considered as a bug and that is why I suggested creating the issue

Comment: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/174 I think it is related

Comment: I fail to understand how a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is related to MapStruct. MapStruct generated a an implementation. Compilation would fall if the target method is not available compile time. So `Boolean getMyVar()` must be there. Apparently its not there runtime, hence the exception. Question: are you sure you have the same version of `MyClassWithMyVar` available compile-time as you have run-time?

Comment: @Filip: I do think a null check is generated. Checkout code generated for: [BooleanMappingTest](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/processor/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/ap/test/bool/BooleanMappingTest.java)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own method in mapstruct. 
Example below for conversion

```
class Entity{
Boolean x;
};
class DTOEntity{
boolean z;
}
```

In Mapstruct Try this

```
@Mapping(target = "z", source = "x", qualifiedByName="getBoolean")
DTOEntity entityToDto(Entity entity);
@Named("getBoolean")
default boolean getBoolean(Boolean x) {
    return  (boolean) x;
}
```

}